# State of xorg support in MacOS Catalina (10.15)

Tags: homebrew, ui, x11

I'm currently setting up a new Mac with Catalina (10.15) and Homebrew. What is the current state of xorg support in this combination?

- Is [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) still maintained, and is it compatible with 10.15? The XQuartz Release page unfortunately does not have compatibility information.
- Homebrew has some Xorg-based apps, like xpdf, but they don't seem to depend on an xorg formula. Their docs only mention, in a single sentence aimed at packagers, "Don’t build X11/XQuartz GUIs as they are a bad user experience on macOS." -- so what is the recommended way to use xorg-based software if one accepts that bad user experience?

Comment: `xquartz` is available through Homebrew, it's the most recent version available. Don't think it gets a lot of developer attention though.